# Not able to customize webchat sendbox(Form field)

Tags: botframework

I want to customize webchat send input field, by adding label tag above the input field and remove the placeholder and add send text instead of icon using react.

Currently, I have tweaked using javascript(Es6)

[image: Screen Shot 2020-01-22 at 11 58 08 AM]

Comment: You say you are "not able to customize webchat" in the title, but then state you have "tweaked using javascript". Were you actually able to make the changes? Also, you tagged this as `reactjs` - is this for a full-fledged React project or using the `window.ReactDOM.render()` version of Web Chat?

Comment: my question is there way to customize bot framework webchat <form> field using react. currently what I have done is by targeting particular class name and appending label or is there anything available from the plugin features and i am using the window.ReactDOM.render() version of Web Chat

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at this time, there is no built in feature of Web Chat that allows the developer to alter the send box (beyond hiding / not hiding it). If you feel strongly about this as a feature others could benefit from, I would suggest you present it as a feature request on the BotFramework-WebChat repo. You can do so [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Enhancement%2C+Pending%2C+customer-reported%2C+Bot+Services&template=feature_request.md&title=).

The method you are using (i.e. altering the DOM directly) is the correct method.

Hope of help!